# Cannot change keyboard repeat/delay in Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, settings, lxde

Settings are located under `Preferences -> Keyboard and Mouse -> Keyboard`.  Adjusting the Repeat Delay and Repeat Interval does nothing.  Neither rates change in the test text box, nor do they change elsewhere, nor are they saved after confirming the settings by clicking OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could not get the GUI to work, but the settings are located in `.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`.  Updating the `Delay=200` and `Interval=30` in the `[Keyboard]` section change the behaviour of the system.  This also updates the values displayed the settings window mentioned in the question, so it seems that there is some issue updating this file from the settings window.

There is a bug here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxinput/+bug/989430